# Python - builtins.MemoryError: in program for counting words in big text file

Tags: python, count, bigdata, counter, cpu-word

It is a program for counting words in big text file. I am counting a words and I display 20 the most common words.

```
    from timeit import default_timer as timer
    from collections import Counter

    start = timer()

    with  open("word5gb.txt", 'r') as input_file:
        file_contents = ""
        for line in input_file:
            file_contents += line
            word_list = file_contents.split() #create word list
            new_list = sorted(word_list, key=Counter(word_list).get, reverse=True)  #sorting
            new_list = list(dict.fromkeys(new_list)) #eliminates duplicates
            print(new_list[0:20])
            print(new_list[-20:-1])        

    end = timer()

    print('\n', "Time: ", round(end - start, 2), "s (", round(((end - start)/60),2), " min)")
```

But when I run program using 5GB txt file, after a while display info about error:

```
word_list = file_contents.split() #create word list
builtins.MemoryError:
```

I have 8GB, windows 64-bit and I am using Python 3.7 64-bit.

I need your help.
How to quickly and simply solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is unnecessary to keep all the file contents in the file_contents variable.

You could save memory by getting rid of this line

```
file_contents += line
```

and just process the file line by line, using line variable instead of file_contents.

If you just need to get the most common words you could update the counter with the words of each line and finally get the most commons using the Counter  most_common method:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from collections import Counter

start = timer()
cnt = Counter()

with open("word5gb.txt", 'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        word_list = line.split() #create word list
        cnt.update(word_list)
    print(cnt.most_common(20))

end = timer()

print('\n', "Time: ", round(end - start, 2), "s (", round(((end - start)/60),2), " min)")
```

Comment: Could you transform the program to get the version you're talking about?

Comment: If you just need to get the most common words you could update the counter with the words of each line and finally get the most commons using the Counter  most_common method:

`
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from collections import Counter

start = timer()
cnt = Counter()

with open("word5gb.txt", 'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        word_list = line.split() #create word list
        cnt.update(word_list)
    print(cnt.most_common(20))

end = timer()

print('\n', "Time: ", round(end - start, 2), "s (", round(((end - start)/60),2), " min)")
`